# PHP: MySQLi Connection available in methods

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

what must i change to transfer the $con to methods inside the class?

It should be available "public" or something.

```
class MyClass {

public function __construct()
{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbu...", "pw") or die("Error");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "db100...") or die("Error");
}

public function doSomething()
{
    mysqli_query($con, "");
}

}
```

Thanks!

PS: I don't want $this->db->query() or something :)

Comment: `PS: I don't want $this->db->query() or something`...well then don't put methods inside the class then. `$this` is required if you're going to access methods or properties on the class itself.

Comment: What is your argument for not wanting to put the connection as a property of the class, i.e `$this->con`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with the procedural version of mysqli, in an object oriented class, you will still need to use `$this`, but a bit differently:

```
class MyClass {
    private $con;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbu...", "pw") or die("Error");
        mysqli_select_db($this->con, "db100...") or die("Error");
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        mysqli_query($this->con, "");
    }
}
```

Ideally though, if you're sticking with object notation, you should just go [object oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) all the way:

```
class MyClass {
    private $con;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new mysqli("localhost", "dbu...", "pw") or die("Error");
        $this->con->select_db("db100...") or die("Error");
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->con->query("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
class MyClass {

  public $con

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbu...", "pw") or die("Error");
    mysqli_select_db($this->con, "db100...") or die("Error");
  }

  public function doSomething()
  {
    mysqli_query($this->con, "");
  }

}
```

... or like this:

```
global $con; 

class MyClass {

  public function __construct()
  {
    global $con;
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "dbu...", "pw") or die("Error");
    mysqli_select_db($con, "db100...") or die("Error");
  }

  public function doSomething()
  {
    global $con;
    mysqli_query($con, "");
  }

}
```

The first option is recommended because the second can cause namespace conflicts